# Were the prizes suppose to include the digital DLC too?

Tags: support, me3missions

On http://www.razerzone.com/me3 it mentions they come with a redeemable code for an Assault Rifle.

Did the prizes include this? If so, where would that code be located? I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Shouldn't you be asking Razer or Amazon instead? SE is associated with neither Mass Effect nor the promotions Razer offers therefor.

Comment: @RavenDreamer I don't think Amazon would respond to me because I didn't make the order.

Comment: I'll pass this on to Lauren, but it probably won't get a proper answer till next week with the long weekend and all.

Comment: @AnnaLear Thanks! No rush.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I received the messenger bag as well. I found my code in a small zippered pouch on the inside of the bag. When I say small, I mean it's really only big enough for my hand. Inside was a small folded slip with the download code.

Comment: Fluttershy saves the day.